# PyParsing bibliographic citations

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm having some trouble with PyParsing. I need to parse some bibliographic information from CVs. An example:

> AuthorA, B., AuthorB, M. R., AuthorC, V., and B. LastAuthor. Some
>   sciency title.  Name of the confernce, City, State, December 3, 2012

I came up with some code to parse out (mainly) the author list and date ... the other information is not particularly important to me.

```
from pyparsing import (Word, Literal, OneOrMore, alphanums, delimitedList, printables, 
    alphas, nums)

family_name = Word(alphanums+'-')
first_init = Word(alphanums+'.')
author = (family_name("LastName") + Literal(',').suppress() + 
          OneOrMore(first_init("FirstInitials") ) )
last_author = first_init("FirstInitials") + family_name("LastName")

author_list = delimitedList(author) + Literal('and').suppress() + last_author

sentence = OneOrMore(Word(printables))
location = delimitedList(Word(printables))
date = Word(alphas) + Word(nums) + Literal(',').suppress() + Word(nums)

citation = (author_list('AuthorLst') + sentence('Title') + location('Location') 
            + date('Date'))

citation.parseString(ntext)
```

However, it farts at the "and" as the distinction between author list and the last author.

I get the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-5d7946dcb775> in <module>()
     15 
     16 
---> 17 citation.parseString(ntext)

/Users/willdampier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.pyc in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1123             else:
   1124                 # catch and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack trace
-> 1125                 raise exc
   1126         else:
   1127             return tokens

ParseException: Expected "and" (at char 40), (line:1, col:41)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What output do you get with your example and current code? (Just to get an idea what "farts" means in this context.)

Comment: what is `Word`, `OneOrMore`, etc? Are these from a regex library? Can you add these import statements for reproducing?

Comment: Edited to add the error message and the imports which are from `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After defining `author`, add this line:

```
author.setName("author").setDebug()
```

to track the matching of `author` expressions. Then to get some better overall diagnostics, change your test line to:

```
author_list.runTests(ntext)
```

With these changes, you'll get output like:

```
Match author at loc 0(1,1)
Matched author -> ['AuthorA', 'B.']
Match author at loc 12(1,13)
Matched author -> ['AuthorB', 'M.', 'R.']
Match author at loc 28(1,29)
Matched author -> ['AuthorC', 'V.']
Match author at loc 41(1,42)
Exception raised:Expected "," (at char 46), (line:1, col:47)

AuthorA, B., AuthorB, M. R., AuthorC, V., and B. LastAuthor. Some sciency title. Name of the confernce, City, State, December 3, 2012
                                        ^
FAIL: Expected "and" (at char 40), (line:1, col:41)
```

So your immediate problem is that you are not handling the trailing ',' before the 'and'. You will also need to add the trailing '.' to your definition of `author_list`.

But from there, your parser of `sentence` will be problematic, as it will process the entire rest of the string. Since your main interest is getting the date, then this might do the job for you:

```
stuff = OneOrMore(Word(printables), stopOn=date)
citation = (author_list('AuthorLst') + stuff('body') + date('Date'))
```

Finally, with respect to your use of results names ("FirstInitials", "LastName", etc.). Well done, this is a feature
I am especially happy with in pyparsing. But you will need to do some isolation of the names from each author reference,
else you will only get the last author's name. To do this, wrap each author in a pyparsing Group:

```
author = Group(family_name("LastName") + Literal(',').suppress() + 
          OneOrMore(first_init("FirstInitials") ) )
last_author = Group(first_init("FirstInitials") + family_name("LastName"))
```

Now your `author_list` should give you a list of substructures. You can see them if you do:

```
print(citation.parseString(ntext).dump())
```

With my changes, I get this for your sample text:

```
[['AuthorA', 'B.'], ['AuthorB', 'M.', 'R.'], ['AuthorC', 'V.'], ',', 
 ['B.', 'LastAuthor'], '.', 'Some', 'sciency', 'title.', 'Name', 'of', 
 'the', 'confernce,', 'City,', 'State,', 'December', '3', '2012']
- AuthorLst: [['AuthorA', 'B.'], ['AuthorB', 'M.', 'R.'], 
              ['AuthorC', 'V.'], ',', ['B.', 'LastAuthor'], '.']
  [0]:
    ['AuthorA', 'B.']
    - FirstInitials: 'B.'
    - LastName: 'AuthorA'
  [1]:
    ['AuthorB', 'M.', 'R.']
    - FirstInitials: 'R.'
    - LastName: 'AuthorB'
  [2]:
    ['AuthorC', 'V.']
    - FirstInitials: 'V.'
    - LastName: 'AuthorC'
  [3]:
    ,
  [4]:
    ['B.', 'LastAuthor']
    - FirstInitials: 'B.'
    - LastName: 'LastAuthor'
  [5]:
    .
```

Still need to suppress the ',' and '.' punctuation, but that is just cleanup. Then you will be able to easily
iterate over your author list and get each author's name.

Comment: That's awesome! I never new about the debugging/testing architecture. I figured it was having a issue with the trailing comma but I couldn't make it work.